# How can I let the user give NL input when showing them an input-view?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I have a capsule that calculates something based on user input. The user needs to tell my capsule an originating country (`FromCountryConcept`), destination country (`ToCountryConcept`), and a text (`LetterContentConcept`). Since the country concepts are `enum`, the `input-view` for those are simple `selection-of`. For the `input-view` for the text I use a `textarea`. All of the code is below and available on github in this repository: [SendLetter-Bixby](https://github.com/Seylox/SendLetter-Bixby/tree/49aff5713c075dbee49f30ed50596a83880dbff7)

When the user uses the Bixby Views to give the required input to Bixby everything works as expected.

**How can I let the user provide input to the shown `input-view` using (spoken or typed) NL input?**

My action `SendLetter.model.bxb` looks like this:

```
action (SendLetter) {
  description (Sends a Letter from one country to another and calculates the cost based on the letter content length.)
  type (Calculation)
  collect {
    input (fromCountry) {
      type (FromCountryConcept)
      min (Required)
      max (One)
      default-init {
        intent {
          goal: FromCountryConcept
          value-set: FromCountryConcept {
            FromCountryConcept(Germany)
            FromCountryConcept(South Korea)
            FromCountryConcept(USA)
            FromCountryConcept(Spain)
            FromCountryConcept(Austria)
            FromCountryConcept(France)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    input (toCountry) {
      type (ToCountryConcept)
      min (Required)
      max (One)
      default-init {
        intent {
          goal: ToCountryConcept
          value-set: ToCountryConcept {
            ToCountryConcept(Austria)
            ToCountryConcept(South Korea)
            ToCountryConcept(USA)
            ToCountryConcept(Spain)
            ToCountryConcept(Germany)
            ToCountryConcept(France)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    input (letterContent) {
      type (LetterContentConcept)
      min (Required)
      max (One)
    }
  }
  output (SendLetterResponseConcept)
}
```

The `input-view` for the country concepts `FromCountry_Input.view.bxb` looks like this (`ToCountry_Input.view.bxb` is equivalent):

```
input-view {
  match: FromCountryConcept(this)
  message {
    template ("Select the country this letter will be sent from")
  }
  render {
    selection-of (this) {
      where-each (fromCountry) {
        // default-layout used
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `input-view` for the text I want the user to be able to input is in `LetterContent_Input.view.bxb`:

```
input-view {
  match: LetterContentConcept(this)
  message {
    template ("Write the content of the letter.")
  }
  render {
    form {
      on-submit {
        goal: LetterContentConcept
        value {
          viv.core.FormElement(letterContent)
        }
      }
      elements {
        textarea {
          id (letterContent)
          label ("Letter Content")
          type (LetterContentConcept)
          value ("#{value(this)}")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're at a prompting moment, so you need to add prompt training.

This will allow the user to use NL to respond to your prompt.

In the training tab, it looks like this:
[image]

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/training.intro-training#add-training-examples-for-prompts